# Need to apply a numerical logic (example column_values/5) to certain column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

Although we can replace the existing columns by applying the numerical logic to each columns individually, but wanted to check if there is a much efficient way to do this

Ineffecient:

```
df=(
df
.withColumn('B', (F.col('B')/5))
.withColumn('C', (F.col('C')/5))
.....)
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **`list`** comprehension with `select` in pyspark.

**`Example:`**

```
df.select("A",*[(col(f)/5).alias(f) for f in df.columns if f not in 'A']).show(10,False)
```